# Problem with constructor that will create rectangle using coordinates of the centers, high (X axis) and width (y axis)

Tags: java, constructor, rectangles

So i need code that consist of 2 classes, method point that already formed and method rectangle that include constructor for creating rectangle itself, rectangle itself should be formed by this test

```
@Test
    public void testRectangle2() {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20, 30, 20, 20);
        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(10, rect.getTopLeft().getX()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getTopLeft().getY()),
                () -> assertEquals(30, rect.getBottomRight().getX()),
                () -> assertEquals(40, rect.getBottomRight().getY()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getWidth(), 20),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getHeight(), 20)
        );
    }
```

Class Point works fine, and i am ading it just for clarity

```
public class Point {
    private int x, y;
    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    public void moveTo(int newX, int newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }
    public void moveRel(int dx, int dy) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is class for Rectangle itself, and it includes both constructor and aditional methods.

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point center;
    public int xCenter;
    public int yCenter;

    public Point getTopLeft() {
        Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
        point.moveRel(- width / 2, - height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public Point getBottomRight() {
        Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
        point.moveRel(width / 2,  height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public int getWidth() {

        return width;
    }


    public int getHeight() {

        return height;
    }
    public Point getCenter() {
       Point center = new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
       return center;
    }
    public Rectangle(int xCenter, int yCenter, int width, int height) {
        this.xCenter=xCenter;
        this.yCenter=yCenter;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }
}
```

Problem is in the constructor it self, it should get values from the test and then form rectangle but it is not doing it.

Comment: Why are you never calling `getCenter()` or otherwise constructing the `Point` that represents the center of the rectangle? That's kind of crucial.

Comment: So `point` is prebuilt class that i cant modify.
And i kinda not sure about how to call `getCenter()` as i am not even sure that i made it corectly, So `getCenter()` and  `public Rectangle(int xCenter, int yCenter, int width, int height)` Is parts that i have problem with

Comment: Nobody is saying you should modify `Point`. You call `getCenter()` like you call any other method. There are a lot of things that you haven't done "correctly", but I don't see anything that you have done so incorrectly that it won't work. The problem is that your rectancle does not have a center because at no point in your code do you initialize the corresponding field.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in this code.

The issue with constructor is that the center point is not created, then the test fails with `NullPointerException` in `getTopLeft/getBottomRight` whichever called first because these methods do not use `getCenter()` method but refer `center` field directly.

So, it should be enough just to use the mentioned getter in the mentioned methods and remove redundant field `center`.

```java
class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public int xCenter;
    public int yCenter;

    public Point getTopLeft() {
        Point point = getCenter();
        point.moveRel(- width / 2, - height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public Point getBottomRight() {
        Point point = getCenter();
        point.moveRel(width / 2,  height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public int getWidth() {

        return width;
    }


    public int getHeight() {

        return height;
    }
    public Point getCenter() {
       Point center = new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
       return center;
    }
    public Rectangle(int xCenter, int yCenter, int width, int height) {
        this.xCenter=xCenter;
        this.yCenter=yCenter;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }
}
```

However, this design has certain flaws that `Rectangle` fields are public and may be changed from outside thus breaking encapsulation principle.  Also, redundant points are created although they might be reused.

An improved version of the Rectangle class is below:

- "immutable" fields
- lazily initialized `topLeft` and `rightBottom` points

```java
public class Rectangle {
    private final int width;
    private final int height;
    private final int xCenter;
    private final int yCenter;
    
    private Point topLeft;
    private Point bottomRight;
    
    public Rectangle(int xCenter, int yCenter, int width, int height) {
        this.xCenter = xCenter;
        this.yCenter = yCenter;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public Point getTopLeft() {
        if (null == topLeft) {
            topLeft = getCenter();
            topLeft.moveRel(- width / 2, - height / 2);
        }
        return topLeft;
    }

    public Point getBottomRight() {
        if (null == bottomRight) {
            bottomRight = getCenter();
            bottomRight.moveRel(width / 2,  height / 2);    
        }
        return bottomRight;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    
    public Point getCenter() {
       return new Point(xCenter, yCenter);
    }
}
```